# DB import from a txt file into SQL server doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm trying to import the following database (which is in a txt file) into my SQL server database:

[Maxmind Free World Cities Database](https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database)

I've defined a proper table and then tried the following query to import:

```
BULK INSERT Cities FROM 'C:\Users\***************\worldcitiespop.txt'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

But the following error comes out:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 1 The bulk load failed. The column
>   is too long in the data file for row 1, column 7. Verify that the
>   field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly. Msg 7301,
>   Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot obtain the required interface
>   ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server
>   "(null)".

It seems as thought there is no new line row terminator.
What can I do to import the DB correctly?

Comment: Did you try `ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'`?

Comment: @gofr1 
Tried now, I still get the same error

Comment: The fact that the download is a .gz file indicates it's a unix style file which will have a LF only as a row terminator. I managed to load about 80240 rows using the import wizard in SSMS before the load failed with some errors. The file therefore is the problem. You might be lucky and some other contributor may have a file fix....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first create `worldcitiespop.fmt` file with this content (file needs a blank line at the very end):

```
10.0
7
1  SQLCHAR  0  10 ","        1  Country                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
2  SQLCHAR  0  100 ","        2  City                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
3  SQLCHAR  0  100 ","        3  AccentCity                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
4  SQLCHAR  0  100 ","        4  Region                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
5  SQLCHAR  0  10 ","        5  Population                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
6  SQLCHAR  0  20 ","        6  Latitude                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
7  SQLCHAR  0  20 "\n"      7  Longitude        SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
```

Then load like this:

```
INSERT INTO Cities
SELECT  a.Country, 
        a.City, 
        a.AccentCity, 
        a.Region, 
        CAST(a.[Population] as int) as [Population],
        CAST(a.Latitude as decimal(10,7)) as Latitude, 
        CAST(a.Longitude as decimal(10,7)) as Longitude
FROM OPENROWSET( 
    BULK 'D:\worldcitiespop.txt', FORMATFILE = 'D:\worldcitiespop.fmt', FIRSTROW = 2
    ) AS a;
```

On my old notebook, this insert lasts ~5 minutes

Comment: Amazing! It worked! thank you very much. In general, what did you do?

Comment: In fmt we determine each column: name, datatype, column separator from txt file, then we load everything via openrwset. The problem with your query (I guess) was in longitude and latitude which bulk insert can not autoconvert in numeric/decimal types, and here in fmt we determine nvarchar datatype for them and than convert them in what we need.