# Why am I getting Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 56 (File_upload)?

Tags: sql-server

I am facing the problem when I am loading data in SQL server using bulk
     loader(SQL loader).Here I am generating my file through java code and at
     the end of the line I write line terminator.

```
my code is -


  BULK INSERT ExcelFile
   FROM 'D:\201606162171840OwnersImportFormat.csv'
     WITH
      (
     -- FIRSTROW = 2,
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'  ,
     FirstRow = 1 --Use to shift the control to next row
    -- ERRORFILE = 'D:\SchoolsErrorRows.csv',
   --  TABLOCK
);

I am getting the error like Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for  
row 1, column 56 (File_upload).
Please tell me where I am going wrong.
```

[Click here to see file data and table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiGom.png)

Comment: Have you tried `ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'`? And what is an encoding of file?

Comment: Hi, default encoding of file  is Cp1252

Comment: Try to select from openrowset, it has similar syntax to bulk insert. If this will not work you can try using *.fmt file where all columns are determine. You can find info on MSDN. Also you can use this answer, but with your settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361053/db-import-from-a-txt-file-into-sql-server-doesnt-work/37364221#37364221

Comment: Hi, When I am writing the file  as .csv format then its default encoding style is cp1252.But when I open this file to notpad++ editor then it is opening as utf-8 encoding

Comment: Maybe you have default convert in utf-8 option on in notepad++. Anyway cp1252 or utf-8 - bulk insert works good with both. Try with fmt file.